# wrong output in search file for word code

Tags: python, regex, function

I have this code to search files for words (and not substrings) and return the lines in which the words are found:

```
def word_search(word, file):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word), flags=re.IGNORECASE))
    return (item for item in file
        if pattern.match(item) == -1)
```

But this code gives back (almost) everything. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your attention

This is the code:

```
sentences = re.split(r' *[\.\?!][\'"\)\]]* ]* *', text) # to split the file into sentences

def finding(word, file):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return (item for item in file if pattern.search(item))   # your suggestion

from itertools import chain # I'm plannig on using more words, and  I dont want duplicate       #sentences. Thats why i use the chain + set. 
chain = chain.from_iterable([finding('you', sentences), finding('us', sentences)])

plural_set = set(chain)

for sentence in plural_set:
        outfile.write(sentence+'\r\n')
```

This gives me the result you see below.

This is the content of the testfile:

> "Well, Mrs. Warren, I cannot see that you have any particular cause
>   for uneasiness, nor do I understand why I, whose time is of some
>   value, should interfere in the matter.  I really have other things to
>   engage me."  So spoke Sherlock Holmes and turned back to the great
>   scrapbook in which he was arranging and indexing some of his recent
>   material.
>
> But the landlady had the pertinacity and also the cunning of her sex.
>   She held her ground firmly.
>
> "Your arranged an affair for a lodger of mine last year," she
>   said--"Mr. Fairdale Hobbs."
>
> "Ah, yes--a simple matter."
>
> "But he would never cease talking of it--your kindness, sir, and the
>   way in which you brought light into the darkness.  I remembered his
>   words when I was in doubt and darkness myself.  I know you could if
>   you only would."
>
> Holmes was accessible upon the side of flattery, and also, to do him
>   justice, upon the side of kindliness.  The two forces made him lay
>   down his gum-brush with a sigh of resignation and push back his chair.

And what the code returns:

> Warren, I cannot see that you have any particular cause for
>   uneasiness, nor do I understand why I, whose time is of some value,
>   should interfere in the matter So spoke Sherlock Holmes and turned
>   back to the great scrapbook in which he was arranging and indexing
>   some of his recent material.
>
> But the landlady had the pertinacity and also the cunning of her sex.
>   She held her ground firmly.
>
> "Your arranged an affair for a lodger of mine last year," she
>   said--"Mr. Fairdale Hobbs."
>
> "Ah, yes--a simple matter."
>
> "But he would never cease talking of it--your kindness, sir, and the
>   way in which you brought light into the darkness I know you could if
>   you only would."
>
> Holmes was accessible upon the side of flattery, and also, to do him
>   justice, upon the side of kindliness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three errors:

1. When a regex fails to match, the matching function returns `None`, not `-1`.
2. You need to use `re.search()` instead of `re.match()` if you want to match in the entire string instead of just at the start of a string.
3. You need to provide the `flags` argument in the correct place:

So it should be something like this:

```
def word_search(word, file):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return (item for item in file if pattern.search(item))
```

Let's see it in action:

```
>>> file = ["It's us or them.\n",
... '"Ah, yes--a simple matter."\n',
... 'Could you hold that for me?\n',
... 'Holmes was accessible upon the side of flattery, and also, to do him justice, upon the side of kindliness.\n',
... 'Trust your instincts.\n']
>>> list(word_search("us", file))
["It's us or them.\n"]
>>> list(word_search("you", file))
['Could you hold that for me?\n']
```

Comment: Also, `flags=re.IGNORECASE` should be an argument to `re.compile()`, not to `str.format()`.

Comment: @ Tim P. Thx. It works better now(I get alot less results). But still sentences wich do not contain any of the words I'm searching for. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: @user3119123: Any example for such a line (and the word you're searching for)?

Comment: @ Tim P. So after some testing I have an example. The code worked on a file with 5 sentences. But on a slightly larger file, with larger sentences I got this. (edited in post). Its a bit late so I wont check on until tommorow. Thanks again for you attention, appreciate it!

Comment: @user3119123: I can't reproduce this - see my edit. How exactly are you using the function?

Comment: @ Tim P. I posted the code as i use it. Maybe it goes wrong somewhere at the splitting?

Comment: Yes, the split is not splitting along sentences correctly, so several sentences may be contained within a single split result. I think you should also split along newlines, and avoid splits within quotes (which your regex appears to be trying to do, but failing). A better solution would likely involve NLTK since sentence parsing is very hard if not impossible with pure regex.

Comment: It's for an assignment, in which we cant use NLTK. So im trying some stuff with regex, but indeed its far from perfect. I'm gonna try something with the newlines and remove the quotes. Thx for your suggestions and for thinking with me! Cheers